# Verify in tests that message ended up on DLQ

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, junit5, activemq-artemis

I am trying to figure out the following scenario:

- Exception occurs during camel route
- `onException()` block for that exception "catches" it, but intentionally does not handle it
- The message ends up on DLQ

This works in "live" code and since the consumer is configured with maxRedeliveries=2, this can be seen in the logs, that two retries happened. After those retries message ends up on DLQ.

However, in tests where we use `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ` and configuration is a bit different, so we have maxRedeliveries=0 in the test configuration.

I tried adding additional route in tests that consumes DLQ:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    LambdaRouteBuilder testRoutes() {
        return routeBuilder -> routeBuilder
                .from("activemq:ActiveMQ.DLQ")
                .id(ROUTE_DLQ_CONSUMER)
                .autoStartup(false)
                .to(MOCK_DLQ_QUEUE_CONSUMER);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to verify DLQ messages, but I see a lot of errors that I am not sure what they mean. And what would be the right way to verify that message ended up on DLQ?

Log:

```
2024-02-01 10:42:24.770  WARN 456652 --- [Item.Delete]] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:45837/api/REST/1.0/data/contact/1111?depth=complete with statusCode: 400]
2024-02-01 10:42:24.771  WARN 456652 --- [mpl$6@64e6f678)] org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server  : AMQ222149: Sending message Reference[115]:RELIABLE:CoreMessage[messageID=115, durable=true, userID=34342e83-c0e6-11ee-bb95-1695ff5186e7, priority=4, timestamp=Thu Feb 01 10:42:24 CET 2024, expiration=Thu Feb 01 10:42:44 CET 2024, durable=true, address=Service.v1.Item.Delete, size=1747, properties=TypedProperties[__HDR_dlqDeliveryFailureCause=java.lang.Throwable: Delivery[1] exceeds redelivery policy limit:RedeliveryPolicy {destination = null, collisionAvoidanceFactor = 0.15, maximumRedeliveries = 0, maximumRedeliveryDelay = -1, initialRedeliveryDelay = 1000, useCollisionAvoidance = false, useExponentialBackOff = false, backOffMultiplier = 5.0, redeliveryDelay = 1000, preDispatchCheck = true}, cause:null, __AMQ_CID=ID:M318-46291-1706780541864-4:2, _AMQ_GROUP_SEQUENCE=0, JMSReplyTo=temp-queue://ID:M318-46291-1706780541864-5:2:1, __HDR_BROKER_IN_TIME=1706780544591, _AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1, __HDR_ARRIVAL=0, __HDR_COMMAND_ID=4, JMSCorrelationID=Camel-ADD0E57089F7D7F-0000000000000001, __HDR_PRODUCER_ID=ID:M318-46291-1706780541864-5:1:1:1, __HDR_MESSAGE_ID=ID:M318-46291-1706780541864-5:1:1:1:1, __HDR_DROPPABLE=false]]@244030696 to Dead Letter Address DLQ from Service.v1.Item.Delete
2024-02-01 10:42:29.570  WARN 456652 --- [r[ActiveMQ.DLQ]] c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - trying to recover. Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pool not open
2024-02-01 10:42:29.581 ERROR 456652 --- [r[ActiveMQ.DLQ]] c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: User name [null] or password is invalid.
2024-02-01 10:42:34.593 ERROR 456652 --- [r[ActiveMQ.DLQ]] c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: User name [null] or password is invalid.
2024-02-01 10:42:39.604 ERROR 456652 --- [r[ActiveMQ.DLQ]] c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: User name [null] or password is invalid.
2024-02-01 10:42:44.609 ERROR 456652 --- [r[ActiveMQ.DLQ]] c.c.j.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ActiveMQ.DLQ' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: User name [null] or password is invalid.
2024-02-01 10:42:45.584  WARN 456652 --- [Item.Delete]] o.a.c.c.j.r.TemporaryQueueReplyManager   : Timeout occurred after 20000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ADD0E57089F7D7F-0000000000000001] on destination temp-queue://ID:M318-46291-1706780541864-5:2:1. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ADD0E57089F7D7F-0000000000000000 on ExchangeId: ADD0E57089F7D7F-0000000000000000) and continue routing.
```